# How to load a WebView on local files, but external to mainBlundle? (iPhone App)

Tags: iphone, webview

I have written a script that download some HTML files into the Documents folder of my app! I want to load this files in my WebView, is that possible?

For example:
If index.html is present in Documents folder, load it, else load index.html in mainBundle!

Thanks to everyone can help me!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just use:

`[webview loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [@"~/Documents/index.html" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]]]]`